# Next-previous pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm pretty new in WordPress !
however I tried hard to know how to add next and previous pages pagination and proudly I **couldn't**  so I asked that maybe someone can helps here

like how to add it and how to choose the number of posts choose in page and this how to style it .. is it has some classes or what ? ^^

that's enough and thanks

Comment: You're proud that you couldn't ??? I think you need to supply default values for 'paged' and 'posts_per_page'. Here's [the WordPress Codex on Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination). Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Meanwhile you can set number of post per page via setting >> reading from admin section as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read how it works in the official [WordPress Documentation about Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination).

There you'll learn about several methods and techniques for WordPress Pagination.

**An basic example for setting up pagination:**

```
<!-- Start of the main loop. -->
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>

<!-- the rest of your theme's main loop -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- End of the main loop -->

<!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->

<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts'     ); ?></div>

<?php else : ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```